# Send email from alias by default, Mail app

Tags: mail.app, email, gmail, alias

In the Mail app, I would like to automatically send new emails from my alias.

I have the alias set up so that it appears as one of the options in the "From" menu when composing an email, but the "Send new messages from" menu in Preferences > Composing only lists my three accounts, without the alias option.

Is there a way to automatically send emails from my alias, without having to choose it each time I compose a new email?

In the Gmail webapp, this can be done, but I'd like to do it from the Mail app.

Comment: Did you find a resolution?

Comment: I did not find a resolution

Comment: @JordanMiguel I'm pretty sure I've found a solution, in case you still might need it, posted it down below

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions.
1st: Half-arsed.

Let's say, you have 2 different email accounts and 1 of them has aliases that you'd like to use, assuming you've already added them in *"Mail Preferences - Accounts - Email addresses"* and marked/selected as "Main" alias.
Then choose in *"Composing - Send new messages from - Automatically select best account"*, and when you'll compose New email if you're **in the folder/account of aliased email** (you clicked on that account in the left panel) it should select that *"Main"* alias email automatically.

2nd: Proper.

When you're adding new Gmail account in Settings on Mac, do NOT add it as Gmail, instead click "Add another account - Mail", then put there your ALIAS email and your [Generated](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/9437157?hl=en) password (that's important!). It will prompt some error but will give a new window.[image: Like this]

In email address put your **alias email**;
User name: your GMAIL account;
Password: GENERATED;
Incoming Mail Server: imap.gmail.com;
Outgoing: smtp.gmail.com; Click Sign In, Done.

You won't have fancy Gmail icon in Settings, but in Mail app your default email will now be **alias email**, and you will be able to select it in *"Composing - Send new messages from"*.

If you also need to use your NON alias email, add it in *"Mail Preferences - Accounts - Email addresses"*, but leave your Alias as default if you want, then when you'll compose New email you'll have an option in the dropdown menu.